# Format function - VB6 to C# conversion

Tags: c#, vb6

What is the C# equivalent of:

```
Public stringValue As String
Public intValue As Integer

intValue = Format(val(stringValue), "00")
```

?

Comment: Look at Int32.TryParse

Comment: That code sample isn't valid, though, is it? `Format` takes in an `int` and returns a `string` but in the sample you're passing it a `string` and assigning the result to an `int` . What is it supposed to be doing? Initializing the `int` from the `string`, or vice-versa?

Comment: I agree, the code as shown in the example doesn't make sense. Can you explain what it is supposed to be doing>?

Comment: The code is parsing a dataset and populating variables. `stringValue` is the data from the dataset and is populating `intValue`. I will update further in a response to jamesstap's comment.

Answer (score 0):

So the vb6 `Format` function converts to string and the `Val` function converts to a number. If you look at the [Microsoft documentation for Val](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/val-function):

```
Val("    1615 198th Street N.E.")
// returns
1615198
```

in c# this can clumsily be converted to

```
string stringValue = "    1615 198th Street N.E.";

// assign to int if int wanted
// throws exception if cannot be converted to int, use Int32.TryParse if you want to handle that
int intValue = System.Convert.ToInt32(
    new string(stringValue.Replace(" ", "").TakeWhile(System.Char.IsDigit).ToArray())
);

System.Console.WriteLine(intValue);
```

it's really going to depend on what your expectations are for what `stringValue` is going to be and what you want returned. Also I don't think you can assign a `string` value to an `int` so willy nilly like you can in vb6. It can definitely be cleaned up but that just depends on what you're doing.

edit:
Since you're testing a `stringValue = "3"` this should work

```
string stringVal = "3";
if(!System.Int32.TryParse(stringVal, out int intValue))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"value={stringVal} not of type int");
}
return intValue;
```

Comment: Thanks jamesstap for your response. The code is parsing a dataset and populating variables. `stringValue` is the data from the dataset and is populating `intValue`. I have tried `intValue = Int32.Parse(String.Format("{0:00}", stringValue)); `, `Int32.Parse(stringValue)`, and other variations, but each variation yields a "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'"

Comment: @user2407030 what are you expecting `stringValue` to be? what string are you testing?

Comment: From the file that I am parsing, `stringValue` looks to be just "3". I tried the `System.Convert.ToInt32(new string(stringValue.Replace(" ", "").TakeWhile(System.Char.IsDigit).ToArray()))` and get the "System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @user2407030 that particular case was only when you could expect a weird string value like the one from the Microsoft documentation. I've updated my answer with your particular use case `stringValue = "3"`

Comment: Using `TryParse` didn't output the FormatException. I think that did it! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @user2407030 great! if that worked can you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If truly replicating the VB6 `Val` function is desired, then `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val` can be used.  It is pretty faithful to the original, and of course can be called from C#.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.val?view=netcore-3.1#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Conversion_Val_System_String_ for the string overload (returns Double).

One aspect where it doesn't return the same result as VB6 is for a string like "3.4.5".  VB6 `Val` will return 34.5, while the .Net `Val` will return 3.4.

No need for exception handling (just like with VB6), if the input can't be converted to a number, no exception is thrown (well, mostly, there are some edge cases) or error returned, the return value is zero.